# HTML: Body bigger height than its content

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

My Google Chrome Extension has a much higher `Body` than the height of its content:

[image][image]

There is no other parent div, however It is possible to expand the settings which increases the height of the `<div id='app'>`

[image]

Isnt it possible to have the `Body` expand with its content, so that the height of the `Body` gets smaller if the height of `<div id='app'>` gets smaller?

This id how I expand the settings `div`:

```
function expandDiv() {
    growDiv1 = document.getElementById('grow');
    if (growDiv1.clientHeight) {
      growDiv1.style.height = 0;
    } else {
      var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
      growDiv1.style.height = "338px";
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: this is the default behaviour do not set any height

Comment: Use `body { height: min-content }`

Comment: @wOxxOm worked for me thx

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also set height property to 100%

```css
div{
height:100%;
}
```